# reproducir archivo de audio m3u en un reproductor html5 jquery

Tags: jquery, json

espero que alguien gentilmente me pueda ayudar a resolver mi dilema, que ya tengo tiempo sin una solución definitiva a mi problema...

Explico que tengo primero....

Este es mi reproductor web

```
 var audio;

 var bg = $('div #audio-info').css('background-image','none');

 $('#play').click(function(){
     var img = 'img/equalizador.gif';
     var bg = $('div #audio-info').css('background-image',"url(" + img + ")");
 });

 $('#stop').click(function(){   
     var bg = $('div #audio-info').css('background-image','none');
 });

 //Hide Pause Initially
 $('#pause').hide();
 $('#title').hide();
 $('.title').hide();    

//Initializer - Play First Song
initAudio($('#playlist li:first-child'));

function initAudio(element){

var song = element.attr('song');
var title = element.attr('title');
var cover = element.attr('cover');
var artist = element.attr('artist');

//Create a New Audio Object
audio = new Audio(' ' + song);

if(!audio.currentTime){
    $('#duration').html('0.00');
}

$("#track1").click(function(){          
    $("audio-info .title").attr('id', 'title'); 
    $('#title').show();         
    var img = 'img/equalizador.gif';
    var bg = $('div #audio-info').css('background-image',"url(" + img + ")");    
});   

$("#track2").click(function(){      
$("#title").removeAttr('id');
$('.title').show();
$('.artist').show();
var img = 'img/equalizador.gif';
var bg = $('div #audio-info').css('background-image',"url(" + img + ")");
});

$("#track3").click(function(){      
$("#title").removeAttr('id');
$('.title').show();
$('.artist').show();
var img = 'img/equalizador.gif';
var bg = $('div #audio-info').css('background-image',"url(" + img + ")");   
});

$("#track4").click(function(){      
$("#title").removeAttr('id');
$('.title').show();
$('.artist').show();  
var img = 'img/equalizador.gif';
var bg = $('div #audio-info').css('background-image',"url(" + img + ")");
});

$("#track5").click(function(){      
$("#title").removeAttr('id');
$('.title').show();
$('.artist').show();
var img = 'img/equalizador.gif';
var bg = $('div #audio-info').css('background-image',"url(" + img + ")");
});

$("#track6").click(function(){      
$("#title").removeAttr('id');
$('.title').show();
$('.artist').show();
var img = 'img/equalizador.gif';
var bg = $('div #audio-info').css('background-image',"url(" + img + ")");
});

$("#track7").click(function(){      
$("#title").removeAttr('id');
$('.title').show();
$('.artist').show();
var img = 'img/equalizador.gif';
var bg = $('div #audio-info').css('background-image',"url(" + img + ")");
});

$("#track8").click(function(){      
$("#title").removeAttr('id');
$('.title').show();
$('.artist').show();
var img = 'img/equalizador.gif';
var bg = $('div #audio-info').css('background-image',"url(" + img + ")");
});

$("#track9").click(function(){      
$("#title").removeAttr('id');
$('.title').show();
$('.artist').show();
var img = 'img/equalizador.gif';
var bg = $('div #audio-info').css('background-image',"url(" + img + ")");
}); 

$('#audio-player .title').text(title);
$('#audio-player .artist').text(artist);

//Insert Cover Image
$('img.cover').attr('src','img/covers/' + cover);

$('#playlist li').removeClass('active');
element.addClass('active');

$(audio).on('ended', function(){
    $('#next').trigger('click');
});      
}


//Play Button
$('#play').click(function(){
audio.play();
$('#play').hide();
$('#pause').show();
$('#title').show();
$('.title').show();
$('.artist').show();
$('#duration').fadeIn(400);
showDuration();
 });

 //Pause Button
 $('#pause').click(function(){
 audio.pause();
 $('#pause').hide();
 $('#play').show();
 });

 //Stop Button
 $('#stop').click(function(){
 audio.pause();     
 audio.currentTime = 0;
 $('#pause').hide();
 $('#play').show();
 $('#title').hide();
 $('.title').hide();
 $('.artist').hide();
 $('#duration').fadeOut(400);
 });

 //Next Button
 $('#next').click(function(){
     audio.pause();
 var next = $('#playlist li.active').next();
 if (next.length == 0) {
    next = $('#playlist li:first-child');
 }
 initAudio(next);
 audio.play();
 showDuration();
 });

 //Prev Button
 $('#prev').click(function(){
 audio.pause();
 var prev = $('#playlist li.active').prev();
 if (prev.length == 0) {
    prev = $('#playlist li:last-child');
 }
 initAudio(prev);
 audio.play();
 showDuration();
 });

 //Playlist Song Click
 $('#playlist li').click(function () {
 audio.pause();
 initAudio($(this));
 $('#play').hide();
 $('#pause').show();    
 $('#title').show();
 $('.title').show();
 $('.artist').show();
 $('#duration').fadeIn(400);
 audio.play();
 showDuration();
 });

 //Volume Control
 $('#volume').change(function(){
 audio.volume = parseFloat(this.value / 10);
 });

 //Time Duration
 function showDuration(){
 $(audio).bind('timeupdate', function(){
    //Get hours and minutes
    var s = parseInt(audio.currentTime % 60);
    var m = parseInt((audio.currentTime / 60) % 60);
    //Add 0 if seconds less than 10
    if (s < 10) {
        s = '0' + s;
    }
    $('#duration').html(m + '.' + s);   
    var value = 0;
    if (audio.currentTime > 0) {
        value = Math.floor((100 / audio.duration) * audio.currentTime);
    }
    $('#progress').css('width',value+'%');
    });
 }
```

Este es el jquery de mi reproductor funciona perfectamente con reproducción de un archivo mp3 individual y selecciona de la lista la siguiente canción sin problemas.

Lo que quiero es incrustarle a la lista de reproducción un archivo m3u para poder reproducir varias canciones un una sola posición de la lista y así poder crear una lista de reproducción que posean archivos m3u cada uno se entiende?.

un ejemplo algo así:

```
<li class="boton" song="merengue.m3u;" id="track1" artist="">Merengues </li>
<li class="boton" song="salsa.m3u;" id="track2" artist="">Salsas </li>
<li class="boton" song="regueton.m3u;" id="track3" artist="">regueton </li>
<li class="boton" song="http://192.168.01:8000/;" id="track4" artist="">Variadas </li>
<li class="boton" song="linkin park.mp3" id="track5" artist="">Linkin park</li>
```

1.- Notese que los 3 primeros link son archivos m3u.
2.- el tercer archivo es un shoutcast streaming.
3.- el ultimo archivo es un mp3 normal...

Quiero es poder hacer funcionar todo junto en armonía con el reproductor que reconozca cualquiera de los play y lo reproduzca y pueda darle siguiente o previo y cambie de posición de lista y reproduzca los audios...

Se que es algo dificil.... el reproductor trabajar prefectamente con shoutcast y mp3 juntos sin inconvenientes, el problema radica en parsear los archivos m3u para que sigan en armonia con el reproductor sin que se rompa el codigo....

P.D.: he intentado parsear el m3u con los dos métodos que hay en github

https://github.com/nickdesaulniers/javascript-playlist-parser

Pero no logro fusionarlo con mi codigo

también prove con :

```
 $.ajax({
 type: "GET",
 url: 'linkin park.m3u',
 success: function(data) {
 //and then parse    
 var playlist = M3U.parse(data);
 $('.title').html(playlist[0]['artist'] + ' - ' + (playlist[0]['title']));
 //$('#prueba2').html(playlist[0]['title']);

 }
 });
```

y no pude terminarlo para que sonara los archivos pero si pude lograr obtener los titulos y artistas...

Para terminar tengo pocos conocimientos de jquery, json, javascript, ajax, pero me defiendo un poco y logro entender muchas cosas, intento, borro, cambio, pruebo,reviso en la consola las fallas, en fin, no me rindo, pero ya esto se me ha vuelto dificil, si alguien me puede orientar en el camino correcto o ayudarme a armar el codigo se lo agradeceria. Si hace falta mas codigo con gusto lo comparto... esto es para un proyecto personal... saludos y muchas gracias gente emprendedora....

Answer (score -1):

¿Pero en armonía todos al mismo tiempo? Si es así debes crear tantos *tags* de audio como sean las fuentes del tipo que sean, y por tener cargados todos antes esperar para después lanzar los *play* de todos al tiempo.
Las listas *m3u* imagino que ya las tienes creadas en esos archivos.

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [answer], ya que lo expuesto, parece más bien un comentario.